# Hyperref Warning & Minitoc

Tags: hyperref, warnings, minitoc

About this code, Overleaf warns me with this message:

**Package hyperref Warning: Difference (2) between bookmark levels is greater than one, level fixed on input line 49.**

Why and how could I correct my code?

Consider that I desire that *Preface* in line 49 not mentioned in First Chapter's minitoc.

Thank you so much!

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[tight, italian]{minitoc}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}

\Large

\title{\color{red}{\Huge{\textbf{BOOK EXAMPLE}}}}
\author{\color{blue}{\Huge{\textbf{AUTHOR}}}}
\date{25 September 2022 --- xx Month Year}

\frontmatter

\maketitle

\dominitoc

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\section*{GENERAL PREFACE}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}GENERAL PREFACE}

\chapter{INTRODUCTORY CHAPTER}

\minitoc %\minilof\minilot
\mtcskip
\pagestyle{plain}

\section{A section}

\newpage

\mainmatter

\part[FIRST PART]{\huge\color{red}{FIRST PART}}

\section{Preface}

%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{I.0\quad\,Preface}

\chapter{First Chapter}
\minitoc %\minilof\minilot
\mtcskip

\section{Preface}

%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{1.0\quad Prefazione}

\section{A}

\section{B}

\section{C}

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\minitoc
\mtcskip

\section{Preface}

%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{2.0\quad Prefazione}

\section{A}

\section{B}

\section{C}

\section{D}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you really want that preface numbered? And if so, how? 0.1, 0.2? And you do want it in the main ToC, jut not any minitoc? Are the current results what you were hoping for? If it's just a warning, you could always just ignore it.

Comment: I'd like that **0.2 Preface** is not in chapter's minitoc but only in ToC.

Comment: Does putting `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\chapterend}` after `\part[...]{...}` and before `\section{Preface}` do what you want?

Comment: Yes, thank you. But Ovrerleaf warnings me again with the same message. Why?

Comment: The warning didn't really have to do with the issue with the minitoc. When hyperref creates the main pdf bookmark contents menu, it thinks it's weird that you have a section listing right after the part listing with no chapter listing in between. Since that's apparently how you want it(?), you can just ignore the warning.

Comment: load the bookmark package after hyperref. It is more reliable if the levels are not continuous.